# Class "PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer" not found

Tags: php, phpmailer, codeigniter-4

I'm using CodeIgniter 4 and I'm trying add PHPMailer to my project via a composer:

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

[image]

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Models\IssueModel;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

class Issues extends Controller {

    public function create() {
        if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {
            .... // some code here
                $issueModel = new IssueModel();

                $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->Host       = 'mai';
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
                $mail->Username   = 'noreply';
                $mail->Password   = 'pass';
                $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
                $mail->Port       = 587;

                ..... // some code here
    }

}
```

And I have an error:

> Class "PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer" not found

Where is a problem?

Comment: Is composer's `autoload.php` being run?

Comment: Composer support is automatically initialized by default.  (https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/concepts/autoloader.html#id4)

Comment: This feels like something wrong with autoloading. Can you verify that those class files are in fact inside the `src` directory, then can you double-check phpmailer's `composer.json` and make sure there's a line to autoload from that directory? Like `"autoload": { "psr-4": { "PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\": "src/" } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on issue on this https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1703

You should run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1703#issuecomment-479945297